How to remove border radius of an OutlinedButton in flutter?
I want to remove OutlinedButton border radius, It has a default border radius I want to have a rectangle shape not a rounded rectangle shape.
Here's my code:
OutlinedButton(
            style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
              side: BorderSide(color: Color(0xffC5C5C5), width: 2.0),
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text(
              "data",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: "GB",
                fontSize: 12,
                color: Color(0xffC5C5C5),
              ),
            ),
          ),


Try this to remove the rounded corners.
OutlinedButton(
                style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0),
                  ),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  //
                },
                child: const Text("press me"),
              )

Result


Here you go:
OutlinedButton(
  style: const ButtonStyle(
    side: WidgetStatePropertyAll(
      BorderSide(color: Color(0xffC5C5C5), width: 2.0),
    ),
    shape: WidgetStatePropertyAll(
      RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  onPressed: () {},
  child: const Text(
    "data",
    style: TextStyle(
      fontFamily: "GB",
      fontSize: 12,
      color: Color(0xffC5C5C5),
    ),
  ),
),


We should use shape property and give the value of BeveledRectangleBorder(), like this:
OutlinedButton(
            style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
              shape: BeveledRectangleBorder(), //To have rectangle shape
              side: BorderSide(color: Color(0xffC5C5C5), width: 2.0),
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text(
              "data",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: "GB",
                fontSize: 12,
                color: Color(0xffC5C5C5),
              ),
            ),
          ),

